# PHP tables, add html class for each column

Tags: php, class, html-table

I have a PHP code for creating tables from mysql query. I want every column of the table to have automatic generated html classes.

For example : `<class="column-1"> for the first column <class="column-2">` for the second and so on.
How can I achieve this?

This is a part of PHP code:

```
$report .= '<table class="sql-table"><thead><tr class="sql-Header-Row">';
    foreach (array_keys($sql_query_times[$SQLkey]["result"][0]) as $field) {
        if ($Report_Name == 'Unsaved Report')
            $report .= '<th><b><a href="javascript: document.SQLForm.submit();" onclick="document.SQLForm.action+=\'&SQL_ORDER_BY[]='.$field.'\'">'.$field.'</a></b></th>';
        else
            $report .= '<th><b>'.$field.'</b></th>';
    }
    $OddEven=array('Even','Odd');
    $report .= '</tr></thead><tbody>';
    for ($row=0; $row<count($sql_query_times[$SQLkey]["result"]); $row++) {
        $report .= '<tr class="sql-Row-'.$row.' sql-'.($OddEven[$row%2]).'-Row">';
        foreach ($sql_query_times[$SQLkey]["result"][$row] as $value)
            $report .= '<td>'.($value).'</td>';//is_array(maybe_unserialize($value))?print_r(maybe_unserialize($value),1):
        $report .= '</tr>';
    }
    $report .= '</tbody></table>';
```

The `<col>` tag is not helpful enough :/ .

Comment: @arkascha The OP wants to add a class to a column, not a row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already show the solution yourself by creating unique class names for your table rows. Just apply the same idea to the columns. Fortunately you already have a suitable key in your foreach loop, you just have to use it:

```
foreach ($sql_query_times[$SQLkey]["result"][$row] as $key=>$value) {
    $report .= sprintf('<td class="column-class-%s">%s</td>', $key, $value);
}
```

Side note: I do not know your database driver or the name structure of the rows elements. In the example above I assume they are simple alphanumeric names that are suitable as a class name. If not you have to convert them, but that does not change the basic idea. So I left away such thing to keep the example simple and readable.